# Fixed left menu with the scrollable content and anchor

Tags: jquery, html, css

As you can see from the fiddle this is a simple page with the menu on the left that is fixed and with a scrollable content.

I want menu to be on the same level as the content, but there is a blank space on the top I don't know how to remove it. So when I scroll down, menu shifts up.

Here is a fiddle:

```
<nav>

<a href="#" data-scroll="top">Top</a>

<a href="#" data-scroll="news">News</a>

<a href="#" data-scroll="products">Products</a>

<a href="#" data-scroll="contact">Contact</a>

</nav>

<div class="wrapper">

<section id="top" data-anchor="top">

    <h4>TOP</h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,</p>

        <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. Mauris    dictum nisl </p>

</section>

<section id="news" data-anchor="news">

    <h4>NEWS</h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>

        <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus. </p>

</section>

<section id="products" data-anchor="products">

    <h4>PRODUCTS</h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. </p>

        <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus.</p>

</section>

<section id="contact" data-anchor="contact">

    <h4>CONTACT</h4>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Quisque feugiat eleifend orci, eget aliquam dolor elementum vel.</p>

        <p>Duis vel augue quis elit ultrices fermentum ut eu risus.</p>

</section>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/1553/

Comment: like this http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/1554/?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this: **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/1554/)**

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right; 0;
    top: 0px; /* changed 100px to 0 */    
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px 0;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
    color:pink;
}
```

**EDIT:** **[Updated Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/1560/)**

For text highlight change this in js

```
if (windscroll >= 100) {
```

to

```
if (windscroll >= 0) {
```

Comment: It is still messed up :(

Comment: what do you mean by messed up here.. share some image representation of expected output

Comment: When I click on "News" link, "Top" link is highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

```
nav {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 100px; /* <-- this is your problem */
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 4px 0;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 100;
  color: pink;
}
```

Comment: But now menu items highlight is messed up. For example if I click on "Products", "News" link will be highlighted. Also if I click on "Top" link, there is a slight "hick up", whole menu shifts up for a bit and than returns back.

Comment: Calculate (find) the offset needed and add it in your javascript function, obviously, `$(this).position().top <= windscroll - 20` doesn't work for you anymore, you need another constant. And put the fixed class at all times,  you don't need an absolute element anymore as it doesn't move now.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `top:100px` from below:

```
nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right; 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px 0;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
    color:pink;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/gUWdJ/1557/)

Answer (score 0):

change the below css in nav 
nav {  <s>position: absolute;</s> <s>top: 100px;</s>}

```
    nav { position: fixed;top: 0;}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gUWdJ/1558/)

Comment: Tnx, this is the closest solution, but there is one more thing. Menu items highlight is messed up. For example if I click on "Products", "News" link will be highlighted.

Answer (score 0):

your css changed to :

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0
}



h4 {
   font-weight: bold;

}

/*p {
    margin: 20px 0;
}

section {
    padding: 20px 0;
}*/

.wrapper {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    /*padding: 28px 0 0 0;*/
    margin-left:130px;
}

nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right; 0;
    top: 0px;

    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 4px 0;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 100;
    color:pink;
}

nav a {
    font-family: helvetica;
color:pink;    
    padding: 2px; 4px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 4px;


    width: 100%;

    font-size:20px;

}

nav a:hover,
nav a.active {
    background: white;
    color:gray; 
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0
}
```

and your js changed to :

```
$('nav a').on('click', function() {

    var scrollAnchor = $(this).attr('data-scroll'),
        scrollPoint = $('section[data-anchor="' + scrollAnchor + '"]').offset().top - 28;

    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: scrollPoint
    }, 500);

    return false;

})


$(window).scroll(function() {

    var windscroll = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (windscroll >= 0) {
        $('nav').addClass('fixed');
        $('.wrapper section').each(function(i) {

            if ($(this).position().top <= windscroll + ($(this).index('section'))*(35)) {
                $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
                $('nav a').eq(i).addClass('active');

            }
        });

    } else {

        $('nav').removeClass('fixed');
        $('nav a.active').removeClass('active');
        $('nav a:first').addClass('active');
    }

}).scroll();
```